# How to detect number of nodes involved in a collision in SpriteKit

Tags: objective-c, ios7, sprite-kit, skphysicsworld

I am creating a shooting game where I am shooting projectiles from one node targeted at enemy projectiles. When the projectile makes contact with two enemy nodes simultaneously, the contact delegate gets called twice. I want to be able to know how many nodes the projectile has come in contact with in order to give the player a 2x bonus.

Can anybody suggest a clean and efficient way to achieve this?

Comment: You could always add hitCount instance var to your projectile and increase it on each contact.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I went with the suggestion by [Dobroćudni Tapir](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2054786/dobro%C4%87udni-tapir) in the comments section.

Added a variable called hitCount as a property of the subclassed projectile SKSpriteNode.

```
@property NSUInteger hitCount;
```

Then in the didBeginContact of the scene

```
-(void)didBeginContact:(SKPhysicsContact *)contact
{
    SKNode *firstBody;
    SKNode *secondBody;
if (contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask < contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask)
    {
        firstBody = contact.bodyA.node;
        secondBody = contact.bodyB.node;
    }
    else
    {
        firstBody = contact.bodyB.node;
        secondBody = contact.bodyA.node;
    }

    if (firstBody.physicsBody.categoryBitMask == projectileCategory && secondBody.physicsBody.categoryBitMask == delusionCategory)
    {
        //Other logic

        RCCProjectile *projectile = (RCCProjectile*)firstBody;
        projectile.hitcount ++;
        [projectile removeFromParent];
    }
}
```

Then, finally in the projectileNode, I overrode the removeFromParent method

```
-(void)removeFromParent
{
    if (self.hitcount >= 2)
    {
        [(LevelScene*)self.scene showBonusForProjectile:self];
    }

    [super removeFromParent];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If your bonus is meant for 2 simultaneous contacts, check out the clean and sexy-sounding `-(NSArray *)allContactedBodies` instance method that you can call on your physicsBody. It returns an array of all other physics bodies it's currently in contact with. Just remember to set the contact bitmasks appropriately.

Comment: Even though this is the only way to go, the problem with this approach is that the contact delegate gets called twice when the projectile hits two enemies at the same time. How can I ensure that the second call is ignored?

Comment: Not sure what your implementation is, but you can try this - when the contact delegate is called for the first time, you set one of the contact bit masks involved (the projectile's mask) to nil. This prevents any subsequent calls to it. You can then reset the bit mask back when applicable.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can store the #hits in an property and kick of method that checks the number of hits after x seconds of an initial hit?

In other words: separate the hit detection from the bonus logic.